# losetup: raspbian-20200505.img: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy

Tags: loop-device

I am trying to shrink the image file from raspbian in Ubuntu18 so that it become small in size and easy to transfer. I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCNjZS-4QmI) where the person uses below command to setup a loop device

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 raspbian-20200505.img -o $((532480*512))
```

But it gives me error:

```
losetup: raspbian-20200505.img: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the reason for this error and how can I resolve it. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You haven't mentioned OS/release details, however your filename implies Raspbian which is neither Ubuntu, nor flavor of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc I am in ubuntu and trying to shrink image file of raspbian

Comment: If you run `df -h` it will show you all the `/dev/loop#` that are in use. Pick the next one that is not in use like `/dev/loop18` or something like that.

Comment: @Terrance that solved the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 2023-07-25:** This answer was written before 22.04 when they changed `df` to no longer list `loop` mounts.  Now you can use `lsblk` to show the loops.

---

It is giving you that message because `/dev/loop0` is already in use.  If you run the command of `df -h` (disk free) which shows you all your mounts that are in use as well as all the `/dev/loop#` mounts.  Pick the next `/dev/loop#` that is not in use for your command.

Example:

```
df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      1.6G  6.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sde1                  212G   92G  109G  46% /
tmpfs                      7.9G   49M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                 9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop1                 172M  172M     0 100% /snap/qt551/27
/dev/loop2                 161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop3                 227M  227M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/136
/dev/loop4                  63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop5                  94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop6                 173M  173M     0 100% /snap/qt551/28
/dev/loop7                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop8                  94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop9                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop10                 74M   74M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/6
/dev/loop11                141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop12                 55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop13                 55M   55M     0 100% /snap/bitwarden/24
/dev/loop14                227M  227M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/123
/dev/loop15                 55M   55M     0 100% /snap/bitwarden/23
/dev/loop16                157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop17                141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/sdf2                  224G  173G   51G  78% /media/Windows
/dev/sdh1                  932G  774G  159G  84% /media/1TB_SHARE
/dev/sdg1                  466G  268G  199G  58% /media/WD500GB
/dev/sda1                  233G  177G   57G  76% /media/250GB_SHARE
/dev/sdd1                  466G   85G  382G  19% /media/ST500GB
/dev/sdc1                  466G  284G  182G  61% /media/500GB
/dev/sdb1                  2.8T  963G  1.8T  35% /media/Seagate
```

as we can see in the above `/dev/loop0-17` are all in use, so the next one we can use is `/dev/loop18` for the command.

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop18 raspbian-20200505.img -o $((532480*512))
```

Comment: ```df``` does not show the loop devices on my system, but ```lsblk``` does

Comment: @ocroquette Thank you for your comment.  You are correct.  Around the release of 22.04 they stopped having `df` list the loop devices.  I added a note at this answer reflecting that.  Thank you!  :)